# Error when calling apply method on BigInt

Tags: scala

Why I get error (`value apply is not a member of scala.math.BigInt`) when I try to execute following code?

```
var a : BigInt = 12;
a.apply("123", 36);
```

`BigInt#apply` is defined in ScalaDoc. Also I tried using implicit `apply`  method invocation, it also doesn't work:

```
a("123", 36);
```

(And second question: It's true *for all objects* that calling `()` is equal to calling `object.apply` or `object apply`  ?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`BigInt#apply` refers to the [object BigInt](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/math/BigInt%24.html), not the [class BigInt](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/math/BigInt.html). Specifically to call this method do the following:

```
BigInt.apply("123", 36)
```

Or, because `apply` is the special method which looks like function application:

```
BigInt("123", 36)
```

Answer (score 3):

`apply()` is a method of `BigInt` [companion object](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/math/BigInt%24.html), not `BigInt` class itself. Thus you can say:

```
val a = BigInt("123", 36)
```

Moreover, what do you expect from `a("123", 36)`? `BigInt` is immutable.